# Hibernate: one-2-one using join table advantages

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm readign the book "Java Persistance with Hibernate" and I faced with example of one-2-one using join table (second edition, page. 230). But I still can't understand the advantages of such approach.

*Can you explain me them? Is it optional one-2-one assosiation. In such case. why can't I simply use nullable Foreign-Key in one of the assosiating tables?*

Comment: why nullable? join one-to-one is exactly mapped 1 to 1 no null FK allowed because commonly they use its PK as FK to another table. so they shared PK(that can't be null).

Comment: One-2-one can be mapped with fk as a separate field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is optional to use a JoinTable in an OneToMany relationship. I did not read this book but I can think in at least two possible advantages of using JoinTable in a OneToOne relationship:

1. *Easy to migrate to a OneToMany or ManyToMany*: let's say that you have an entity Person OneToOne Address, all works fine for years. However, now you have a new business rule that says that Person ManyToMany Address, so you have to write scripts to migrate data and change your table structure. If you have a JoinTable you just need to change the relationship.
2. *You can delete records from the JoinTable instead of the Entity table*: in some scenarios this may be an advantage. Again using our Person OneToOne Address, if you want to delete the Address of a Person you can just delete it from the relationship.

Cheers,

Comment: I also have read that we should use join table in one-2-one relationship, when the relationship is optional.